# How to view the collation setting in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, collation

I'm working with an ancient `SQL Server 8.00.194`, and I need to know the collation setting of the database and specific column.

I've naively tried to use [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information), but it seems that there were no such thing as `sys.databases` (same for `sys.columns`, `sys.tables`):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid object name 'sys.databases'.

Also I have tried to view properties from UI with Management Studio, but it breaks all the time:

> Cannot show requested dialog.
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (SqlManagerUI)

**UPD.** I kinda know that this is possible, because somebody has changed the collation on one column on this server, and that's why I'm doing this.

Comment: *if* I recall correctly, you want the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects. It's been a long time since I had access to 2000 instance. I highly recommend that you find a migration oath off it.

Comment: Also, why is it **never** been patched?! That instance is 20 years out of date! 8.0.194 was the RTM version. There's been 4 services packs since then. What do you have have against updates?

Comment: You used the *wrong* documentation. That's for SQL Server 2019. Online docs go only [as far back as 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/). SQL Server 2000 is no longer supported (the oldest version in mainstream support is 2016)

Comment: Back then the docs came in the installation CD. Rich kids could use their ISDN lines to download it in a day or so, others just waited for the MSDN subscription pack.`Books Online` is actually one of the best docs produced, far better and detailed than current docs by any vendor.

Comment: Seriously, how much data is in that server? Given the size of servers back then, you could probably just put everything in a SQL Server Express instance nowadays, *and* get better reliability and performance

Comment: @Larnu It's not me, it's not even my organization, we just have to support it.

Comment: How can you "support" an unsupported, and completely unpatched, version of SQL Server? Supporting it would mean getting the updates installed and getting it switched off.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually our dev server have gigabytes of data and it's very actively used. I don't know what's going on on production, though

Comment: @Larnu Somebody wrote a software for it back in 2000's which is hard to replace today. That's why the owners of this server want to pay for supporting it, even in a modern software like I'm building today

Comment: Simply GBs is little data - a typical SSD has 500GB and multiple times the performance of a 2000-era RAID array. SQL Server Express's limit is 4 cores, 10GB (data). If the old application uses deprecated features though, 20 years is long enough for MS to remove them

Comment: That still doesn't explain why it's not been patched once in 20 years though @astef . Part of supporting is patching. The 2000 RTM version has several security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Larnu It's not "tech support" or something. It's software which uses the database, and it must be able to work with SQL Server 2000. Actually, there's a lot of modern software which "supports" it. Hopefully, all this software is not going to upgrade the server.

Comment: If you are intending to support something this old, you need to the tools that match it. IIRC Enterprise Manager was the predecessor to SSMS (introduced in 2005).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the metadata views have changed (or rather, first appeared) in SQL Server 2005. Before that, you could query the following:

```
select * from master..sysdatabases;
select * from sysobjects;
select * from syscolumns;
```

An easier way would be looking at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views - these are ANSI standard and existed even in 2000, in almost the same form as they are now. In particular, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` shows column collation, that's for certain.

Comment: `Invalid object name 'sysdatabases'.`, but works for `sysobjects` and `syscolumns`. Great!

Comment: These were actual tables, not views, so you might need to try `master..sysdatabases` instead. My memory is pretty good, but not that good :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar(256), DATABASEPROPERTYEX('database_name','collation'));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**